# How to create a web service in Sharepoint to allow a cloud server to make calls?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We need to do a SharePoint Integration. How to create a web service in Sharepoint to allow a cloud server to make calls? I just need to get files from a Folder and create a folder.

Comment: SharePoint libraries and lists already have REStful web servece built in.

Comment: Creating a farm solution also allows you to deploy a webservice in the ISAPI folder. It's more flexible as you create the service and read files/folders yourself using the server-side API.